# Push Pull Oscillator

Tags: oscillator

Does anyone know how to build a push/pull oscillator or a similar square wave oscillator?

Comment: The simplest oscillator is just an inverter connected back to itself, but that's too trivial to be an answer.

Comment: I would like a nice square wave

Comment: @endolith: that would not work. An inverter connected to itself will usually not oscillate, but instead stabilise and waste power. Instead you will need at least 3 in a ring configuration.

Comment: @Thomas: Ok, ok, a Schmitt-input inverter.  :D  http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/logic/log16.gif

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One Schmitt-trigger inverter (74LS14) together with an RC circuit feeding it will do a pretty good job of creating a simple oscillator. Adjust the RC time constant to adjust the frequency.

[image: Schmitt-trigger oscillator]

Comment: I think that produces a nice sawtooth wave, which might be good enough.

Comment: You only need one Schmitt-input inverter, as I linked above, and it should produce a square wave, not a sawtooth.  The input of the inverter will be a sawtooth, but the output will be a square.  http://www.electro-tech-online.com/attachments/electronic-projects-design-ideas-reviews/18327d1206915388-twinkling-led-matrix-schematic-needed-cmos-schmitt-oscillator.png

Comment: For some reason in college we chained a few of them together. It might be that we didn't use the RC circuit to create a delay at the time and were instead relying on the propagation delay of each of the gates. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a 555 Timer in an astable configuration feeding a D-type falling edge triggered flip-flop.

Answer (score 1):

The [Kalitron](http://www.vk6fh.com/vk6fh/kalitron.htm) is the classic push-pull oscillator. They aren't used much these days, but were quite popular at one time in the valve era, often using a double-triode valve.

Answer (score 1):

Going more basic, a positive feedback OP-AMP circuit can be used to build a square wave oscillator.